# How to keep track of the number of times a user has been mentioned?

Tags: discord, discord.js

In my bot, I have a message counter that stores the number of times a user sent a message in the server.
I was trying to count how many times a user got mentioned in the server. Does anyone know how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `message.mentions.members` (or `message.mentions.users`) to see the mentions in a message. You can store the number of mentions for every user: every time they are mentioned, you increase the count.

```js
var mention_count = {};

client.on('message', message => {
  for (let id of message.mentions.users.keyArray()) {
    if (!mention_count[id]) mention_count[id] = 1;
    else mention_count[id]++;
  }
});
```

Please note that `mention_count` will be reset every time you restart your bot, so remember to store it in a file or in a database to avoid losing it.

Edit: below you can see your code applied to mentions: every time there's a mention to count, it gets stored in the `level` value of the score.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.guild) return;
  for (let id of message.mentions.users.keyArray()) if (id != message.author.id) {
    let score = client.getScore.get(id, message.guild.id);
    if (!score) score = {
      id: `${message.guild.id}-${id}`,
      user: id,
      guild: message.guild.id,
      points: 0,
      level: 0
    };
    score.level++;
    client.setScore.run(score);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for responding..I was following a tutorial & I removed levels and I want to store mentions in level .Here is code for points or messages:
`let score; if (message.guild) {
score = client.getScore.get(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
 if (!score) {
      score = { id: `${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`, 
               user: message.author.id, 
               guild: message.guild.id, 
               points: 0, 
               level: 1 }
    }
    score.points++;
    client.setScore.run(score);
  }`  Can you rewrite and store mentions in level

Comment: worked perfect.. thanks a lot <3 . Here, one more thing how do we protect counting mentions if user mentions himself ?

Comment: You can check if `id != message.author.id`. I've updated the code ;)